# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie not working in custom login system

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created my custom login system, but `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.memb___id, false);` not working.

Method is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.UserModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsValid(user.memb___id, user.memb__pwd))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.memb___id, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

And when i checking with `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)` it returns `false`.

I have check `user.memb___id` is not null and in tutorial where i have seen it's working.

Have some ideas why?

P.S. I'm using Framework 4.5.1

Comment: Could you ensure `<authentication mode="Forms">` exists in web.config? When you debug, did your code reach to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.memb___id, false);`? Where are you accessing `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)`?

Comment: `<authentication mode="Forms">` no there wasn't this line. And thats was the problem, thanks, i saw alot comments about this line but all time i get error, not it works.